# How can I replicate a page in the same document using node.js, google drive api and google docs api?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-docs-api

The closest I found to this was the Google Drive API file.copy, however you cannot use it to copy a specific page. So I tried using get method to get the page content and then inserting it via batchUpdate method, but Get doesn't seem to have the same model as update.

In the code below, I basically copy an entire file with the google drive API and rename it as "Looping Test", then use the get method to get the content from page 9 and 10 and insert it into the batchUpdate method, replicating 5 times.

```js
return await new Promise(async function Criar_Alterar_DOCS() {
try {
    const modelo = 'id do documento'; // document id 
    const Titulo_Novo = 'Teste do looping'; // document title
    const paginaInicial = 9; //home page number
    const paginaFinal = 10; //end page number
    const numeroDeReplicas = 5; //number of times pages will be replicated
    const copyResponse = await drive.files.copy({
        auth: oAuth2Client,
        fileId: modelo,
        requestBody: {
            name: Titulo_Novo,
        }
    });
    const id_documento = copyResponse.data.id;
    console.log("ID documento:", id_documento);
    const response = await docs.documents.get({
        auth: oAuth2Client,
        documentId: id_documento,
    });
    const conteudoOriginal = response.data.body.content;
    //select the apges
    const paginasParaReplicar = conteudoOriginal.slice(paginaInicial - 1, paginaFinal);
    const paginasArray = paginasParaReplicar.map((pagina) => ({
        ...pagina
    }));
    //replicate the pages
    for (let i = 0; i < numeroDeReplicas; i++) {
        for (const pagina of paginasArray) {
            await docs.documents.batchUpdate({
                auth: oAuth2Client,
                documentId: id_documento,
                requestBody: {
                    requests: [{
                            insertText: {
                                location: {
                                    index: 1,
                                },
                                text: '\n',
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            insertText: {
                                location: {
                                    index: 1,
                                },
                                text: 'Página replicada:',
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            insertText: {
                                location: {
                                    index: 1,
                                    /
                                },
                                text: JSON.stringify(pagina),
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            });
        }
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Erro ao criar o documento:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Erro ao alterar o documento");
}
})
});
```